# Wordpress Login & Register works in localhost but don't work on server

Tags: login, wp-login-form

how are you ?
i have a Ridiculous problem. i created a ajax login and register function in wordpress . they works without any problem in localhost,but they don't work when i upload this project on server,i don't have any problem in register function ,user can register successfully.but the login function on server don't work . i research on internet , but i can't find any good solution.please help me . thank you.

[my login page address](http://wordpress.masami.ir/login/)

Comment: Does the default login screen work?

Comment: can you please share your action code logintosite ?

Comment: Check php version on local and live sever.

Comment: check php version and php extensions of server and checek also .htaccess

Comment: #milo , hi my friend. Yes its workin on default login page. I found thats reason.i use ( Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) by BestWebSoft plugin ) and i use that's shortcode ( [bws_google_captcha] ) . I have problem When i use that shortcode in my custom login form. The defualt login form structure  have a bottum that will send data as post method when we click that.but  Since the i use ajax to send my data , i confront with this problem.i so confused :-(

Answer (score 0):

***jQuery codes:***

```
jQuery('form#loginFormSubmit').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var $userName = $this.find('#userNameLogin').val();
    var $password = $this.find('#passwordLogin').val();
    // var $_nonce = $('meta[name="_nonce"]').attr('content');
    var $_nonce = $this.find('#nonceLogin').val();
    var $rememberMe = $this.find('#rememberMe').prop('checked');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: customData.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'loginToSite',
            userName: $userName,
            password: $password,
            rememberMe: $rememberMe,
            _nonce: $_nonce
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                $('.loginRegisterResponse').fadeIn().addClass('successToLogin').find('p').text(response.msg);
                let delay = 3000;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location = response.redirect;
                }, delay);
            } else {
                $('.loginRegisterResponse').fadeIn().find('p').text(response.msg);
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {

        }
    });
});
```

***ajax php codes:***

```
check_ajax_referer('ajax_login_form', '_nonce', true);

$loginInstance = new registerAndLogin($_POST['userName'], $_POST['password']);
$response = [];
$success = true;
$userName=$loginInstance::$userName;
$password = $loginInstance::$password;
$rememberMe=isset($_POST['rememberMe']);

$user = wp_authenticate_username_password(null, $userName, $password);

if (is_wp_error($user)) {
    $success = false;
    if (!$success) {
        $response['success'] = $success;
        $response['msg'] = __("User name or password are incorrect", THEME_NAME);
    }
    wp_die(json_encode($response));
}

$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $userName;
$creds['user_password'] = $password;
$creds['remember'] = true;

$userLoggedIn = wp_signon($creds, false);
if (is_wp_error($userLoggedIn)) {
    $success = false;

    if (!$success) {
        $response['success'] = $success;
        $response['msg'] = $userLoggedIn->get_error_message();
    }
    wp_die(json_encode($response));
}

if ($success) {
    $response['success'] = $success;
    $response['redirect'] = home_url();
    $response['msg'] = __("hi ", THEME_NAME) . $userName . __(' , you signed in to site successfully', THEME_NAME);
}
wp_die(json_encode($response));
```

***And html code :***

```
<form id="loginFormSubmit" class="forms_form" action="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>" method="post">
<fieldset class="forms_fieldset">
    <div class="forms_field">
        <input class="forms_field-input" id="userNameLogin" type="text" name="userName" placeholder="<?php echo __('username', THEME_NAME); ?>"
            required autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="forms_field">
        <input id="passwordLogin" type="password" class="forms_field-input" name="password" placeholder="<?php echo __('password', THEME_NAME); ?>"
            required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto my-1">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="rememberMe">
                <?php echo __('Keep me Signed in', THEME_NAME); ?></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="forms_buttons">
    <button type="button" class="forms_buttons-forgot">
        <?php echo __('Forgot password?', THEME_NAME); ?>
    </button>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo __('Log In', THEME_NAME); ?>" class="forms_buttons-action">
</div>
<div class="group loginRegisterResponse">
    <p></p>
</div>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[bws_google_captcha]'); ?>
<?php wp_nonce_field('ajax_login_form', 'nonceLogin'); ?>
```